# Developing a model to predict the amount of new money brought in by the customer after deploying a campaign

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, modeling, supervised-learning

Background:
Marketing Measurement team works on driving the discipline of ‘test and learn’ within business's direct marketing channels (Email, Direct Mail and so on). For EM and DM campaigns, to measure the impact of marketing campaigns, they run the equivalent of randomized control trials at a very large scale, comparing the average new money brought in by a ‘treated’ population against a homogeneous ‘control’ group, to arrive at the incremental impact, a.k.a. the lift, attributable to the campaign. They measure the campaign population for 90 days from the date on which the campaign was sent, to get to the lift results.

Business problem:
They would like to be able to **predict the 90-day impact of the campaign earlier, say, by day 30.** This would make for faster decision-making on which campaigns are doing well (or not) and should be repeated (or stopped). For this to happen, they would like to predict the new money brought in, once the campaign goes out, which can then be aggregated up to get to campaign-level results.

No.of Records: 1.28 M

No.of Variables: 327

Objective:
To predict 90 day new money due to a campaign by day 30 based on customer/campaign attributes and post campaign activities

I would like to know the best predictive modelling approach in this case. If machine-learning used here, what can be the best technique?

Tools available: R, Python